# Drupal 7: cancel user registration if a wrong field value has been submitted

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, user-registration

I have a Drupal 7 with 1 field added to registration form - a List with possible values **Robot** / **Male** / **Female**:
[image]

```
# select * from field_data_field_gender;
 entity_type | bundle | deleted | entity_id | revision_id | language | delta | field_gender_value
-------------+--------+---------+-----------+-------------+----------+-------+--------------------
 user        | user   |       0 |         6 |           6 | und      |     0 | Male
 user        | user   |       0 |         5 |           5 | und      |     0 | Male
 user        | user   |       0 |         7 |           7 | und      |     0 | Female
 user        | user   |       0 |         1 |           1 | und      |     0 | Male
```

The first value **Robot** is a default value - to prevent SPAM robots from registering at my site. Is there a way to cancel user registration, when a new user submits the registration web form with the default **Robot** value? (i.e. only **Male** and **Female** values are allowed).

I've looked at the core Trigger module, but don't see anything suitable there.

I've looked at the [hook_user_presave](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--user--user.api.php/function/hook_user_presave/7) and [hook_user_insert](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--user--user.api.php/function/hook_user_insert/7) API docs, but don't see a way there to cancel an ongoing user registration. (I was expecting to do that by returning a special value from those methods...)

Thank you!
Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [hook_form_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) and add a new validate function where you'll check the value of the field you want to check.

Comment: Thank you, I've found a good example using validators in the Pro Drupal 7 Development book too

Answer (score 0):

You can also implement your own captcha tests using the drupal module http://drupal.org/project/captcha

Which is what you are doing. This will make the test your are creating a little more portable.